# Issues with installing Streamlit

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, streamlit

I tried to install `streamlit` on my macOS but it does not work. I followed the directions on the website. What should I do?

Comment: Hi Margot! What commands did you run? What were the error messages?

Comment: I tried to used the 'pip install streamlit' however nothing occurred in my terminal

Comment: `pip` just stuck indefinitely, showing no output? If it's the case, try downgrading pip version to 19.X. I just had this problem 2 days ago